# Perl: Can I use pattern matching to find certain lines in a log file

Tags: arrays, perl, pattern-matching

I have a log file with this type of content:

```
Mon Nov 19 11:00:01 2012
Host: myserver
accurev-ent inuse: 629


Mon Nov 19 12:00:01 2012
Host: myserver
accurev-ent inuse: 629
```

Using Perl, I have figured out how to remove the empty lines and put the non-empty lines into an array.  Now I'm trying to match the present month, date and year.  I.e., I'm trying to grab all of the lines that have `May, 21`, and `2013` (this file is the product of a script that runs everyday and 24 times each day.  I don't need the `hh:mm:ss` data.

I keep trying to pattern match this in the following vein:

```
foreach $prod (@prod)
{
  # Sun May 19 02:00:01 2013
  if ($prod =~ ((/Sun May 19/) && $prod =~(/2013$/)) )
  {
    print "Howdy! \n"; # just using to indicate success
  }
}
```

Can I do this via pattern matching or should I try to split this and find the data match?  By the way, once I find the match I need to put the line containing *inuse* into an array and find the largest number for the day.

Comment: I would check out Date::Manip for more reliable ways to parse dates and compare them

Comment: @qwwqwwq: Good point: [`Date::Manip`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Date%3A%3AManip) is one of a very large number of date manipulation modules.  For the current purposes, they might be overkill, but it is very valid to mention them.  There's a whole section of http://search.cpan.org for [Date](http://search.cpan.org/modlist/Data_and_Data_Types/Date) handling and another for [Time](http://search.cpan.org/modlist/Data_and_Data_Types/Time), not to mention the [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DateTime) suite of modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);

# The active regex looks for today's date
# The commented out regex looks for dates in the current month
# If you provide a suitable timestamp (seconds since the epoch),
# you can generate the pattern for an arbitrary date by changing
# time (a function call) to $timestamp.
my $pattern = strftime("%B %d \\d+:\\d+:\\d+ %Y", localtime(time));
# my $pattern = strftime("%B \\d+ \\d+:\\d+:\\d+ %Y", localtime(time));
# print "$pattern\n";
my $regex = qr/$pattern/;

# my @prod = <>;

foreach my $prod (@prod)
{
    # print "Check: $prod\n";
    if ($prod =~ $regex)
    {
        print "$prod\n";
    }
}
```

This uses `strftime` (from POSIX) to create a regex string with the current month and year in the correct places, and handles strings of digits where the day and time components should be.  It then creates a quoted regex with `qr//`, and applies that to each entry in the `@prod` array.  You can make the `\d+` matches more rigid if you wish; whether it is worth doing so depends on the cost of an extraneous match. (One version of the current regex is more lenient than it could be, recognizing the 99th and 00th of May, and also May 20130, etc; they both allow invalid times through).  All these are fixable by tweaking the regex without materially affecting the answer.

Comment: @jonathon, This is helping me zero in on the month but everytime I try to modify the regex for the date number, it gives no output.  The date would be %e, wouldn't.  I was thinking the pattern would be --> my $pattern = strftime("%B %e \\d+:\\d+:\\d+ %Y", localtime(time));  But it seems I'm not getting.  Too bad there isn't an emoticon for a bloody forehead (from banging it against a wall).

Comment: @jonathonLeffler, I ran into a problem when the date changed from May 31, 2013 to June  1, 2013.  Apparently the date I'm working with inserts a space in front of a single digit day of the month.  So, May 31 (which has one space between Ma(y 3)1 reads with two spaces when the date became Ju(n  )1.  The parenthesis is to indicate the problem area.  The match no longer works and won't until June 10.  I can't change my data. What I'm curious about is, is there a way to take into account this change, in the construction of the regex so that the match still occurs correctly?

Comment: Put a `\s+` in place of the blank in `%B\s+%d`; or, more precisely, use `%B  ?%d` (which has two blanks in it, though SO Markdown disguises that; it looks for 1 or 2 blanks between month name and the day number)

Comment: I couldn't get either to work.  Perhaps part of the problem is related to the what is returned from 'scalar localtime()'.  Thanks for getting back to me so quick and thanks for all of the help.

Comment: Print the regex string.  I omitted a backslash in `%B\\s+%d` (sorry).  And note that the other had two blanks in it.  For writing in comments in SO, it would be safer written as `%B {1,2}%d` (one or two blanks), but that is very verbose.  But tweaking the regex for this should be trivial; it is the sort of thing that you should be able to do very quickly and easily.

Comment: In case of doubt, **print!**  Adding `print "[$pattern]\n";` to the script shows `[June 04 \d+:\d+:\d+ 2013]`; the `%d` format includes a leading zero.  A quick study of the man page for [`strftime()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strftime.html) shows that the `%e` format puts a blank in place of the leading zero.  So, change the original format string to: `"%B %e \\d+:\\d+:\\d+ %Y"`.  And, for pity's sake, print the value you're struggling with to see what the problem is!

Comment: @jonathonLeffler.  I put print statements in early yesterday.  I had checked out the strftime() man page and had tried %e in the regex.  I also tried the '%b {1,2}%d'.  The only thing that seems to work is to manually pad dates 1 through 9 with a preceding zero and use %d in the regex.  I have a record of the variations I tried but there seems to be no way to display them here.  Again, thanks for the help you have provided.

Comment: @jonathonLeffler.  Today, I found out what the issue was with using the %e.  I moved the code over to a Linux box and the code worked without a problem.  So apparently %e works with *nix but not with Windows OS (like Windows 7).

Comment: Ugh!! That sort of thing is a big problem.  You could post-process the output of the `strftime()` with `%d` replacing the leading `0` with a space, thus matching the actual input format.  Or you could make the regex more flexible.  The choice is yours.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty regexp:

```
my @prod = ('Mon Nov 19 11:00:01 2012', 'accurev-ent inuse: 629');
foreach $prod (@prod)
{
  # Sun May 19 02:00:01 2013
  if ($prod =~ /^\w+ (\w+) (\d+) ..:..:.. (\d+)$/)
  {
    print "Hodwy: $3 $1 $2\n";
  }

  if ($prod =~ /inuse: (\d+)$/)
  {
    print "Yo: $1\n";
  }
}
```

Yields

```
Hodwy: 2012 Nov 19
Yo: 629
```

Comment: That seems to be selecting dates in Nov 2012 when it was only supposed to select dates in May 2013...

Answer (score 0):

You said that you needed totals for each day.  Here's my go at it.  I hope the comments I've added are sufficient.  I've used array indices though I'm pretty sure this can be done by regex back references, which I've not had much luck with.

Figured I'd fix my misread, why not.

```
open(FILE, "<stackoverflow.data");
my @prod = <FILE>;
close(FILE);

# Strip newlines.
s/\n// for @prod;

my $data; # Hash to store data.


for (my $i = 0; $i < $#prod; $i) {
    my $date  = $prod[$i];                 # First line.
    my $host  = $prod[$i + 1];             # Second line.
    my $inuse = parseInuse($prod[$i + 2]); # Third line.

    $date =~ /^\w+ (\w+) (\d+) .+? (\d+)$/;
    $date = "$1 $2 $3";

    # Initialize inuse value for date.
    if (!defined($data->{$date})) {
        $data->{$date} = 0;
    }

    # Replace stored inuse value if current loop inuse is greater.
    if ($inuse > $data->{$date}) {
        $data->{$date} = $inuse;
    }

    print "Processing $i raw($prod[$i]) sep(date: $date, host: $host, inuse: $inuse) split($inuse)\n";

    # Skip blank line;
    $i += ($prod[$i + 3] =~ m/^\s*?$/) ? 4 : 3;
}

print "\nTotals:\n";
my $matchdate = 'May 19 2013'; # Set to undef to show all.
#$matchdate = undef;

foreach my $date (sort keys %{$data}) {
    if (defined($matchdate) && $date ne $matchdate) {
        next;
    }
    print "$date: $data->{$date}\n";
}


sub parseInuse
{
    my $i = shift;

    my @parts = split(': ', $i);
    $i = @parts[1];
    $i =~ s/\s\+//g;

    return $i;
}



# Mon Nov 19 11:00:01 2012
# Host: myserver
# accurev-ent inuse: 629
# 
# Mon Nov 19 12:00:01 2012
# Host: myserver
# accurev-ent inuse: 800
# 
# Sun May 19 02:00:01 2013
# Host: myserver
# accurev-ent inuse: 629
# 
# Sun May 19 02:00:01 2013
# Host: myserver
# accurev-ent inuse: 1000
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Just to clarify, I don't need to total for each day.  I need to find the largest number for each day.

Comment: Ah.  Sorry, read that wrong.  You'd be able to use the hash for that also, replacing the push with a value check.  Good luck.

Comment: Figured I'd fix my misread.  Why not?  You should be able to combine the date parsing from @JonathonLeffler and have it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.012;

use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
use List::Util qw/max/;

local $/ = "\n\n";
my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
    pattern   => '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y',
    locale    => 'en_US',
    time_zone => 'America/Chicago',
); 
my @records;
for my $record (<DATA>) {
  my ($timestamp, $host, $inuse) = split ("\n", $record);
  $host =~ s/Host: //;
  $inuse =~ s/accurev-ent inuse: //;
  push @records, { timestamp => $parser->parse_datetime($timestamp), 
                   host => $host,
                   inuse => $inuse,
                 };
}

say max map {$_->{inuse}} grep {$_->{timestamp}->ymd() eq '2013-05-21' } @records;

__DATA__
Mon Nov 19 11:00:01 2012
Host: myserver
accurev-ent inuse: 629

Mon Nov 19 12:00:01 2012
Host: myserver
accurev-ent inuse: 629

Sun May 19 02:00:01 2013
Host: myserver
accurev-ent inuse: 629

Tue May 21 02:00:01 2013
Host: myserver
accurev-ent inuse: 1200

Tue May 21 02:00:01 2013
Host: myserver
accurev-ent inuse: 62

Tue May 21 02:00:01 2013
Host: myserver
accurev-ent inuse: 29
```

gives:

```
1200
```

You can fairly trivially change your filter range (say, for the max between 8am and 10pm, the max over a week's period, etc) by changing the test used in grep.